# $index does not exist in ng-repeat - the answer is inside my original post

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have a problem getting $index inside a ng-repeat when trying to bind it to checkbox. First, I assign an array that looks like:

var_dump from php:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(9) {
        ["first_name"] => string(3)
        "emp" ["last_name"] => string(5)
        "loyee" ["username"] => string(4)
        "emp1" ["email"] => string(22)
        "blabla@gmail.com" ["id"] => string(3)
        "539" ["rights_type"] => string(1)
        "3" ["editProfile"] => bool(true)["sendMessage"] => bool(true)["editApps"] => bool(false)
    }[1] => array(9) {
        ["first_name"] => string(3)
        "one" ["last_name"] => string(4)
        "more" ["username"] => string(4)
        "emp2" ["email"] => string(19)
        "blabla@gmail.com" ["id"] => string(3)
        "540" ["rights_type"] => string(1)
        "0" ["editProfile"] => bool(false)["sendMessage"] => bool(false)["editApps"] => bool(false)
    }["isEmpty"] => bool(false)
}
```

my code looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees.result track by $index" ng-if="employee.username">
    <th class="col-md-1" scope="row">{{employee.username}} - ({{employee.first_name}} {{employee.last_name}})</th>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employees.result.$index.editProfile"></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employees.result.$index.sendMessage"></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employees.result.$index.editApps"></td>
</tr>
```

This object is being attached to the $scope in the controller. Important to say that the ng-repeat does work and I get the right values of first name, username etc, it's just the $index that I can't get.
When I try to just print {{$index}} i get nothing. I tried to delete the "isEmpty" key from the array but it did not help as well. Any ideas?

Comment: where is `$index` defined?

Comment: This is not an array: {0:"value1",1:"value2",isEmpty:false}

Comment: you are going to need to post your actual code to get help. `employees{0:"value1",1:"value2",isEmpty:false}` is not an array, it's and object. and array has brackets `[ ]`

Comment: and employees.result would not point to anything

Comment: employees.result also does not seem to be defined

Comment: nor is `employee.username`

Comment: I added some more info so it's more clear to you guys, again, employees.result is included and i'm able to get info from it. the only problem is the index.

Comment: @RoeeDistler, in the future please feel free to add your completed solution as an answer - [self answers are perfectly accepted here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I've opted to edit it out of your question and add it as a community wiki answer - if you'd like to post it as an answer yourself, ping me (@HPierce) and I will happily delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Roee-distler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6728214/roee-distler) originally edited their solution into the question.*

---

All i had to change is employees.result to employee and it actually updated employees.result (every single cell of the array separately), so it looks like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees.result track by $index" ng-if="employee.username">
    <th class="col-md-1" scope="row">{{employee.username}} - ({{employee.first_name}} {{employee.last_name}})</th>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.editProfile"></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.sendMessage"></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.editApps"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I think the issue is that when you are referencing `employees` inside of a loop that is currently looking at a single `employee`

as I mentioned I have never used `$index` so I am not sure but I would also double check if you need to reference it in there (as your WORKING code does not reference it at all)

In your code try changing:

```
<td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employees.result.$index.editProfile"></td>
```

to

```
<td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.result.editProfile"></td>
```

In the case that it DOES need to be referenced, I would imaging the reference would look more like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.result[$index].editProfile">
```

as indexes are normally referenced.

Comment: well, when i dump it(as you can see in my post) it says array(3).. i just don't get why this is not an array

Comment: I wrote this (or was writing it), prior to your updating your code. So it's based on your original post.

Comment: oh i see, so any other ideas based on the current one? the only thing i can think of that might make it not an array is when i json_encode it before it's being assigned to the JS

Comment: so is the issue that the values for `ng-model="employees.result.$index.editProfile"` etc not being set? Basically, you need to be clearer about what it is you are trying to do, or expect to be happening.

Comment: also since you are looping through and array and you have defined each index to be `employee` maybe try `employee.result.$index.editProfile`  or  `ng-model="employee.result.editProfile">` - in other words, drop the `s` since that is refrencing the entire array, not the individual item you are currently on

Comment: yes, so i have a table of checkboxes. All these values you see like username and first name are loaded just fine. The only problem is the value i try to bind to ng-model. when using $index in ng-model I get nothing bound, when at the same time i try to just print $index in the page and do not get anything as well. Bottom line $index does not exist, and employees.result does, so either employees.result structure is wrong or i really don't know what else could it be

Comment: honestly I have never used $index in looping through and array (nor have I dumped and outside file for the array) however I suspect it is simply in the way you are referencing in the checkboxes. check my last response and try those out.

Comment: i use "employee in employees.result" and when i refer to employee.username for example i don't need to use employee.result.username

Comment: yes, but again, you are using `employee` and it is working hold on let me update my answer to show you what i mean

Comment: hey HolyMoly, first, thanks a lot for your patience. I tried all these and maybe i shouldn't be working with $index. Assuming I have this array, how would i assign the checkboxes values back to this array so i can post it to the backend later on without using $index? i'd be happy to learn a different way.

Comment: how you are testing/checking if a value is actually being assigned to the model?

Comment: it's not, since $index does not exist so this whole "employees.result.$index.editProfile" (for example) does not exist as well. when i try to just print {{$index}} inside the ng-repeat i get nothing. if i can get $index to exist, the rest will work. when i replace $index with static value like 0 for example, it works.

Comment: exactly. when you use dot notation you are generally referencing properties on an object, either getting them or creating them -  which is why i originally suggested taking it out, or putting it in brackets if you are trying to use it AS an index to retrieve from that index. Why are you trying to print index? are you trying to fid out what iteration the loop is on? If you are trying to confirm it is working, then the fact you have you list being printed shows it's working and looping is happening correctly. Index is only telling Angular to use indexes not keys to loop.

Comment: when you create model on the view, you should be able to retrieve that data ohhhhh! you know what? I think you are not referencing your controller from the view and you need to be.

Comment: I am referencing it, and i do not to print $index just trying to see if it exists, i only need it for these different check boxes to bind to different cells of my array.

Comment: I use $index in the notation cause i need the check box values to be saved in the array so i can assign it back to the backend, how'd i assign it all otherwise? if i use employee and not employees i think it's not assigning it to employees.

Comment: i dont see it being referenced in you ng-model. if the controller attached to that view was name `foo` then your `ng-repeat` should look like `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo.employee.result.editProfile">`

Comment: ohh my god it actually does! thank you soo much! so for whoever looks at it in the future, using employee.editProfile will do the work for what i've tried as employees.result.$index.editProfile.

Comment: and again when you use dot notation, you are referencing a PROPERTY on an object, so unless your object has a property names `$index` then angular does not know what you are talking about. Indexes are accessed in brackets `[ ]` so if i had an employee object who was third in my array it would be `employee[2]` to access it. This is why it is more likely you need to be using `employee.result[$index].editProfile` because then you are asking for an INDEX not a property on an object.

Comment: you should update your question with your new code so that it is clear what it was that worked

Comment: also note that you have but your new property directly into employee object, if you WANT it in the employee's `results` property, simply doing the same thing but using `employee.results.editProfile ` should put it there. Again, update your code and I will update my answer to reflect what it was i told you that worked to make it clearer for others ;)

Comment: actually it updates employees.result when i just use employee..you can review my new code and see. your way might work too though, i don't know which one is better

Comment: neither is better, there is only what YOU want - depending on how you want the info organized and how you want to access it/ use it in your code. What is 'better' is whatever is clearer, and most organized ;) so glad you got it working. Now on to the next bug (coming soon, as they always do) - happy coding!